# How to Bind ComboboxItem Text to Combobox Text?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, itemtemplate

This is a `ComboBox` `ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue" Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Foreground="Lime"></TextBlock>  
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to use `Texblock.TextTrimming` at the `TextBlock` above. This `TextBlock` will be the `ComboBoxItem` at screen, but I don't know what to put at `TextBlockText`. What should I bind?

I usually see examples where they put: `Text={Binding CustomClass.CustomProperty}`, but I need to make it generic. So it will work for every `ComboBox` of the application.

What can I put at Text?

Please, I am trying this for 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If tou want it to be generic just use `{Binding}`

Example:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="130" Width="167" Name="UI" >
    <Grid >
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Items}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Lime"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add("Stack");
        Items.Add("Overflow");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

And if you are using a custom object you can just override the `ToString` method so it displays what you want in the combobox

Example

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Stack" });
        Items.Add(new CustomObject { Name = "Overflow" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> _items = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<CustomObject> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }

}

public class CustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

Same as above

Result:

[image]

Comment: when I do this, it appears something like "System.Windows.Controls.Combobox" at text.

Comment: what type of object are you adding to your combobox?

Comment: Updated answer with better examples